# How to create an array of dataframe by filtering a data frame with a Seq of lists in Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

One `Df1` with all data, one of the column with `vl1,vl3,vl4,vl2,vl3,vl4..etc` and another dataframe `valueDf` with a single column which have unique values vl1,vl2,vl3..etc

I want to split `valueDf` into an array of 4 dataframes like

```
Df(0)=(vl1,vl4,vl5)
Df(1)=(vl3,vl2,vl6)
Df(2)=(vl7,vl8,vl9)... etc
```

So that i can do `leftsemi` join on Df1 and write in 4 different locations

```
/folder_Df(0)/
/foldwer_Df(1)/.. Etc
```

I tried doing a `randomSplit` as below

```
val Dfs = valueDf.randomSplit(Array.range(1,5).map(_.toDouble), 1)
```

But now I have set of values which need to go into `Df(0),Df(1),Df(2)` based on this `list (vl1,vl4,vl5),(vl3,vl2,vl6),(vl7,vl8,vl9).`

Comment: The question is not clear, can you please add some explanation and expected output to it?

Comment: added some info @AminMal